# How to use struct pointer from C in Python?

Tags: python, ctypes, kotlin-native

This is a snippet from a C header for a Windows DLL that was generated by Kotlin Multiplatform/Native:

```c
typedef struct {
  struct {
    struct {
      // ...
    } root;
  } kotlin;
} libnative_ExportedSymbols;
extern libnative_ExportedSymbols* libnative_symbols(void);
```

From C, you would access the struct `root` [like this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-dynamic-libraries.html#use-generated-headers-from-c):

```
libnative_ExportedSymbols* lib = libnative_symbols();
lib->kotlin.root. // ...
```

How can I access it from Python? It seems that all official samples have been removed. So I tried this without success:

```
import ctypes

libPath = "path/to/libnative.dll"
dll = ctypes.CDLL(libPath)
pythonInt = dll.libnative_symbols()

print(type(pythonInt)) # <class 'int'>
print(pythonInt) # A number, e.g. 1190351680

CPointer = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)
cLong = ctypes.c_long(pythonInt)
cAddress = ctypes.addressof(cLong)
cPointer = ctypes.cast(cAddress, CPointer)

print(type(pythonInt) == type(cPointer.contents.value)) # true
print(pythonInt == cPointer.contents.value) # true
try:
    print(cPointer.kotlin.root)
except AttributeError:
    print("AttributeError")  # AttributeError
try:
    print(cPointer.contents.kotlin.root)
except AttributeError:
    print("AttributeError")  # AttributeError
try:
    print(cPointer.contents.value.kotlin.root)
except AttributeError:
    print("AttributeError")  # AttributeError
```

Comment: Set aside Kotlin and build yourself a simple C struct, then try accessing that alone from Python.

Comment: If I did that following the pattern Kotlin uses I would have exactly the same problem. If I did it differently, it would not help me at all.

Comment: Read the docs about `.restype`. The default `c_int` return type won’t work esp. assuming 64-bit pointers. You’ll also need to derive a `Structure`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Kotlin, but given the C structure described here's a C DLL with that structure and the Python code to call it.  The structures need to be derived from `ctypes.Structure` and the return type of the function needs to be declared via `.restype` and not left to the default of (usually 32-bit) integer.  Casting the return value after-the-fact is too late if it was meant to be a 64-bit pointer.

**test.c**

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct {
  struct {
    struct {
        int a;
    } root;
  } kotlin;
} libnative_ExportedSymbols;

libnative_ExportedSymbols g_lib = {7};

API libnative_ExportedSymbols* libnative_symbols(void) {
    return &g_lib;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Root(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ('a', ct.c_int),

class Kotlin(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ('root', Root),

class Symbols(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ('kotlin', Kotlin),

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.libnative_symbols.argtypes = ()
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = ct.POINTER(Symbols)

lib = dll.libnative_symbols()
print(lib.contents.kotlin.root.a)
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: I cannot verify that your code works because `test.c` is different from my header, but the approach with subclasses of `Structure` and `restype ` does work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996543/443836), but closer to the question:

```
import ctypes

class Root(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("foo", ctypes.c_bool)]

class Kotlin(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("root", Root)]

class Libnative_ExportedSymbols(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("kotlin", Kotlin)]

libPath = "path/to/libnative.dll"
dll = ctypes.CDLL(libPath)
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Libnative_ExportedSymbols)
libnative = dll.libnative_symbols().contents
print(type(libnative.kotlin.root)) # <class '__main__.Root'>
print(libnative.kotlin.root) # <__main__.Root object at ...
```

Note that the following approach without `POINTER` would also work, but may cause [errors down the road](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74998629/443836):

```
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = Libnative_ExportedSymbols
libnative = dll.libnative_symbols()
print(type(libnative.kotlin.root)) # <class '__main__.Root'>
print(libnative.kotlin.root) # <__main__.Root object at ...
```