# How to call a field of CFUNCTYPE?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a DLL (`.dll` for Windows, `.so` for Linux) and this autogenerated C header file for that DLL (excerpt):

---

**Edit notes**

**tl;dr:** I have updated my header excerpt and Python code because I had left out too much.

**Details:** I had left out a bunch of declarations in the header that I deemed unimportant but that turned out to be crucial (revealed by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75000278/443836)). Additionally, I had reduced struct nesting and renamed a struct to reduce clutter. (`kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib` was just `myLib`.) But since the accepted answer was created based on the actual DLL (as requested in the comments and shared outside of Stack Overflow), I have also revised my header excerpt and Python code to be consistent with that DLL and thus the accepted answer.

---

```
typedef struct {
  // #region
  // The details of most of these declarations are not important,
  // but as it turned out, their memory requirements in the 
  // binary layout are:

  void (*DisposeStablePointer)(libnative_KNativePtr ptr);
  void (*DisposeString)(const char* string);
  libnative_KBoolean (*IsInstance)(libnative_KNativePtr ref, const libnative_KType* type);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Byte (*createNullableByte)(libnative_KByte);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Short (*createNullableShort)(libnative_KShort);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Int (*createNullableInt)(libnative_KInt);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Long (*createNullableLong)(libnative_KLong);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Float (*createNullableFloat)(libnative_KFloat);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Double (*createNullableDouble)(libnative_KDouble);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Char (*createNullableChar)(libnative_KChar);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Boolean (*createNullableBoolean)(libnative_KBoolean);
  libnative_kref_kotlin_Unit (*createNullableUnit)(void);

  // #endregion
 struct {
   struct {
     struct {
       struct {
         struct {
           const char* (*createMessage)();

            // More nested structs here
            // (irrelevant for this question)

         } klib;
       } marcoeckstein;
     } com;
   } root;
 } kotlin;
} libnative_ExportedSymbols;
extern libnative_ExportedSymbols* libnative_symbols(void);
```

I want to call the function `createMessage` from Python. I have tried this:

```
import ctypes

class Klib(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("createMessage", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_char_p))]

class Marcoeckstein(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("klib", Klib)]

class Com(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("marcoeckstein", Marcoeckstein)]

class Root(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("com", Com)]

class Kotlin(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("root", Root)]

class Libnative_ExportedSymbols(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("kotlin", Kotlin)]

dll = ctypes.CDLL("path/to/dll")

#region
#The following two lines turned out to be wrong. See below.

dll.libnative_symbols.restype = Libnative_ExportedSymbols
libnative = dll.libnative_symbols()

#endregion

libnative.kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib.createMessage()
```

On Windows I get:

`OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00007FFA51556340`

On Linux I get:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

On Windows, I have also tried `WINFUNCTYPE` instead of `CFUNCTYPE`, but I got the same error.

The wrapper generator [ctypesgen](https://github.com/ctypesgen/ctypesgen) generates the same type for `createMessage` as I did manually.

So what is going on here? How can I call a field of `CFUNCTYPE`?

---

### Partial answer (edit)

As [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364) noted in a comment, I needed to change this code...

```
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = Libnative_ExportedSymbols
libnative = dll.libnative_symbols()
```

... to this:

```
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Libnative_ExportedSymbols)
libnative = dll.libnative_symbols().contents
```

This change turned out to be necessary but not sufficient. I got no error now, but `createMessage` was not properly called. It returned an empty instance of `bytes`, but the function had been implemented to always return a non-empty string.

---

### Additional Notes (edit)

- There is a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987486/how-to-use-struct-pointer-from-c-in-python).
- The DLL and header file were automatically created by [Kotlin Multiplatform/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-dynamic-libraries.html#use-generated-headers-from-c), but this is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: I'm not a `ctypes` expert, but I believe you're telling Python that the `libnative_symbols()` function returns a struct, when it's actually returning a pointer to the struct.

Comment: [Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987486/how-to-use-struct-pointer-from-c-in-python/)

Comment: You’re calling it correctly in the efit, but perhaps Kotlin has a memory management issue or Kotlin strings aren’t strictly compatible with C `char*`.   If a link to the DLL was posted  it would help

Comment: You can find the artifacts [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qfi8qos19ekwr4t/AAAReAVR_uNn3zq0vXcWBf4aa). The code deviates a bit from my simplified code in the question. Most notably, `createMessage` is not nested in `mylib`, but `kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib`.

Comment: I have removed the artifacts and updated the question so that crucial information is not lost.

Comment: You are too quick!  I was not sure whether I could still edit your answer after accepting it, so just in case, I postponed that. It's done now. 

Comment: I didn't realize you'd just edited the question a few minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr (edit by author of the question)

You cannot ignore the declarations before the struct `kotlin`. You do not necessarily need exactly fitting declarations for these in Python, but you need at least placeholders:

```
class Libnative_ExportedSymbols(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("funcn", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None) * 12),  # placeholders
        ("kotlin", Kotlin),
    ]
```

This is already enough to get the solution to work, but it results in a memory leak, because the string returned by `createMessage` uses unmanaged memory. Thus, we need the pointer to that memory, and we need to free it with the `DisposeString` function (a service funtion provided by the tool that built the DLL and header files).

```
class Klib(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("createMessage", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(POINTER(ctypes.c_char)))]

// ...

class Libnative_ExportedSymbols(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("func", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)),
        ("DisposeString", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))),
        ("funcn", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None) * 10),
        ("kotlin", Kotlin),
    ]
```

Now `createMessage()` does not return the standard Python type `bytes` anymore, but `ctypes.LP_c_char`, which we have to convert ourselves:

```
def to_bytes(p):
    return ctypes.c_char_p.from_buffer(p).value

pointer = libnative.kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib.createMessage()
message = toBytes(pointer) # pointer.contents is only the first char.
```

Finally, we free the memory:

```
libnative.DisposeString(pointer)
```

---

### Original answer

With the actual DLL posted in the comments, I was able to resolve calling `createMessage`.  It is actually the 13th function pointer in the nested structure, so the layout has to match.  I didn't define the full nested structure but just the compatible memory layout.

I figured it out by writing a C .exe (provided below) to see if the DLL worked and what the base address of the structure and the function address of `createMessage` were, and consulting the linked `libnative_api.h`.

**test.c** - C code to validate DLL is working and returning a string.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libnative_api.h"

typedef libnative_ExportedSymbols* (*PSYM)(void);

int main() {
    HMODULE h = LoadLibraryW(L"libnative.dll");
    if(h == NULL)
        printf("load failed\n");
    PSYM plibnative_symbols = (PSYM)GetProcAddress(h,"libnative_symbols"); 
    if(plibnative_symbols == NULL)
        printf("get failed\n");
    libnative_ExportedSymbols* lib = plibnative_symbols();
    // addresses of the structure and function
    printf("%p %p\n", lib, lib->kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib.createMessage);
    const char* m = lib->kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib.createMessage();
    printf("msg: %s\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Output - Note there is an extra string printed by the DLL.

```
00007FFAB4526340 00007FFAB44E0840
createMessage() was called.
msg: The int is not there.
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

# binary-compatible layout.
# createMessage is the 13th function pointer in the nested layout.
# I suspect for Kotlin the DisposeString function should be called,
# so I wrote the return value of createString as an actual pointer
# so Python wouldn't automatically convert to a bytes object and
# lose the pointer value.

class Mylib(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("func", ct.CFUNCTYPE(None)), # void pointer placeholder
                ("DisposeString", ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char))),
                ("funcn", ct.CFUNCTYPE(None) * 10), # 10 more void pointer placeholders
                ("createMessage", ct.CFUNCTYPE(ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)))]

def to_bytes(p):
    '''Return the null-terminated C string at address p as a bytes object.'''
    return ct.c_char_p.from_buffer(p).value

def to_address(p):
    '''Return the memory address of the ctypes pointer.'''
    return ct.c_void_p.from_buffer(p).value

dll = ct.CDLL('./libnative')
dll.libnative_symbols.restype = ct.POINTER(Mylib)

libnative = dll.libnative_symbols()
print(f'{to_address(libnative):016X} {to_address(libnative.contents.createMessage):016X}')

p = libnative.contents.createMessage()
print(to_bytes(p))
libnative.contents.DisposeString(p)
```

Output - Note the address of the structure and function match the C .exe.

```
00007FFAB1BF6340 00007FFAB1BB0840
createMessage() was called.
b'The int is not there.'
```

Comment: Wow, so much effort - thanks a lot! I rarely ever work with binary stuff, so I was completely unaware that I could not just ignore the 12 declarations before the struct `mylib` (or actually `kotlin` in the real DLL). Just adding the placeholders in `Libnative_ExportedSymbols` already does the trick: `_fields_ = [("funcn", ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None) * 12), ("mylib", Mylib)]`

Comment: Today, I can finally go to bed with relief, but question and answer are now hard to understand for others, so I will need to edit my question tomorrow, and if you don't mind, I will also edit your answer by adding a concise solution tailored to my edited question (without other people needing to think about the DLL).

Comment: @MarcoEckstein Yes, when interfacing between languages the binary layout is very important so for this type of question and simplifying the header removes important information.  The actual libnative_api.h was definitely needed.

Comment: I have updated question and answer to match each other.

Comment: Note that ignoring DisposeString may be leaving a memory leak.

Comment: Comparing to the [Kotlin docs for C](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-dynamic-libraries.html#use-generated-headers-from-c), you are right. However, when I do `message = libnative.kotlin.root.com.marcoeckstein.klib.createMessage(); print(message); libnative.DisposeString(message); print("Disposed")`, `"Disposed"` will not be printed, and there is also no error. (Note that in my code, `libnative` is already the pointer contents.) What's going on there?

Comment: Or actually, thinking about it again, you may not be right. It must apparently be called in C, but `createMessage()` returns `<class 'bytes'>`, and if I am not mistaken, this is a built-in Python type, so it should be garbage-collected, should it not?

Comment: See my answer closely. In `ctypes`, `ct.c_char_p` converts the returned pointer to a `bytes` object and the pointer is lost, so if the pointer is needed use `ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)` to keep the pointer and cast to `c_char_p` to access the string. I used a helper function to retrieve the null-terminated string from the pointer and use the pointer to free the string.  It gets a bit convoluted to manage C allocations from Python.

Comment: Also, the `bytes` object is garbage-collected when `c_char_p` is used, but it is created as a **copy** of the the allocated C string, but *that* string still needs to be freed.  In my code the helper function `to_bytes` creates the copy and then `DisposeString` frees the C string.  I'd wrap the whole `createMessage`, `to_bytes`, and `DisploseString` in a Python function and return the final `bytes` object to make it look cleaner.

Comment: You are right. It works now. I could also experimentally confirm that there is a memory leak without `DisposeString` and no memory leak with it. I had wrongly assumed that `c_char_p` is a shorthand for `POINTER(c_char)`. Since [ctypesgen](https://github.com/ctypesgen/ctypesgen) generates `c_char_p` as the return type for `const char* (*createMessage)()`, I should probably create an issue there, right?

Comment: The whole interaction with the DLL now seems so low-level and verbose to me that I can hardly believe Python programmers are doing this on a regular basis. Is there really no better abstraction layer? Do Python developers maybe usually ignore the memory leak and get away with it often enough so there is not enough pain in the community?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250885/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-marco-eckstein).